# What's the polite way of describing someone's behaviour that appears to be self-righteous?

Tags: phrase-requests

Most of the [synonyms for self-righteous](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/self-righteous) are deprecating.

One of the wonderful things about the English language is that most ideas have a word for the [positive connotation](http://www.ecenglish.com/learnenglish/lessons/what-are-connotations), and a word for the negative connotation.

I'm trying to find the positive connotation for someone's behaviour being self-righteous. (In the context of trying to work with them in a team).

My question is: **What's the polite way of describing someone's behaviour that appears to be self-righteous?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may say that they are always on the ***on the right side of*** things. The idea is that self-righteous people consciously stick to the right side (as they see it).

ODO:

> **[on the right side of](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/on_the_right_side_of)**
>
> *PHRASE*
>
> **1** On the safe, appropriate, or desirable side of.
>
> ‘her portrayal of his neurotic wife falls just on the right side of
>   caricature’
>
> **1.1** In a position to be viewed with favor by.
>
> ‘he hasn't always remained on the right side of the law’

Comment: That's brilliant.

Answer (score 0):

The positive, flip side of someone being self-righteous is that

**s/he has a strong sense of justice**

[***justice***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/justice)

> The quality of being fair and reasonable

(Oxford)